# Deserialization of abstract types in Dart

Tags: dart, serialization, deserialization

Please consider the following code segment, declaration of one base class and two extenders.

```
abstract class Animal {
  final bool flag;

  Animal(this.flag);
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  final String name;

  Cat(this.name, bool flag) : super(flag);

  Cat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        super(json['flag']);
}

class Fish extends Animal {
  final int memory;

  Fish(this.memory, bool flag) : super(flag);

  Fish.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : memory = json['memory'],
        super(json['flag']);
}
```

What is the best practice of serializing and deserializing the following list?

```
List<Animal> animals = [Cat('Nancy', true), Fish(10, false)];
```

So, how to serialize the type information for each class in order to construct the appropriate instance upon deserialization?

*The serialization code is ommited for the sake of simplicity, however it would return a map of the member fields. The code above is only an example - there is no meaning in the structure or the data.*

**EDIT:** I would prefer not using any library or code generator, but using the internal capabilities of the language.

Any suggestion is appretiated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to figure that out, so I provide my naive solution for the problem. However, if anyone gives a better approach, I will mark that as an answer.

My naive solution is to decorate every JSON result with a 'type' field that contains the name of the subclass. Then I could create a factory for the base type that constructs the appropriate instance depending on that 'type' field. The full code:

```
abstract class Animal {
  final bool flag;

  Animal(this.flag);

  factory Animal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    switch (json['type']) {
      case 'cat':
        return Cat.fromJson(json);
      case 'fish':
        return Fish.fromJson(json);
      default:
        throw 'Invalid animal type';
    }
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  final String name;

  Cat(this.name, bool flag) : super(flag);

  Cat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        super(json['flag'].toString() == 'true');

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {'type': 'cat', 'name': name, 'flag': flag.toString()};
  }
}

class Fish extends Animal {
  final int memory;

  Fish(this.memory, bool flag) : super(flag);

  Fish.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : memory = json['memory'],
        super(json['flag'].toString() == 'true');

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {'type': 'fish', 'memory': memory, 'flag': flag.toString()};
  }
```

Obviously, during deserialization the list items should be mapped using the factory method as follows:

```
var data = jsonDecode("[{'type':'cat','name':'Nancy','flag':'true'},{'type':'fish','memory':10,'flag':'false'}]");
List<Animal> list = data.map((e) => Animal.fromJson(e)).cast<Animal>().toList();
```